# How to resize an empty container movieclip in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, resize, movieclip, children

I have an empty movie clip which I have added children to via addChild. I would like to be able to scale this movie clip by half so that all it's children's dimensions are halved. Changing the height and width properties of the container doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myclip.scaleX = myclip.scaleY = 0.5;
```